# React/redux: Not saving in state as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I am building a review app. I am using json-server to do post request. My database looks like this

```js
[{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Tom Cruise",
    "image": "http://placeholder.pics/svg/300x200/000000",
    "title": "Hiring Manager",
    "employeeId": "22222222",
    "funFact": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "dateOfJoining": "04/12/2013"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Julius Caesar",
    "image": "http://placeholder.pics/svg/300x200/fdfdfd",
    "title": "Sales Executive",
    "employeeId": "33333333",
    "funFact": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "dateOfJoining": "04/12/2016"
  }
]
```

Here is my add Action

```js
//Add Employee
export const addEmployee = employeeData => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:3004/employees", {
      employeeData,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
    .then(response =>
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_EMPLOYEE,
        payload: response.data.employeeData
      })
    )
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

And here is my reducer

```js
case ADD_EMPLOYEE:
  return {
    ...state,
    employees: [action.payload, ...state.employees],
    loading: false
  };
```

Everything works fine. The problem is the way it is stored in the database which is like this

```js
{
  "employeeData": {
    "name": "Manpreet Sandhu",
    "title": "bootstrap 4",
    "funFact": "cccZCZCZ",
    "image": "CZCZCZC",
    "employeeId": "ZCZCZC",
    "dateOfJoining": "C"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "id": 7
}
```

I want to remove "employeeData" added before each entry.

This is what i receive in my action 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [axios document](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases),

- `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`

in your action thunk,

```
//...
axios
    .post("http://localhost:3004/employees", {
      employeeData,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
//...
```

you have put the `headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }` in the `data` argument

I guess, what you would do, should be something like this

```
//...
axios
  .post("http://localhost:3004/employees",
    employeeData, //data
    { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } } //config
  )

// or
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:3004/employees',
  data: employeeData,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
})
//...
```